# I can't post any mentions on rich embed's

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

ok so i made a auto message code here. When someone join in server, my bot will be send a "Welcome to server". But
 i cant see any tag-ping something like that just numbers.

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {

  const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "gelen-giden");
  if(!channel) return;

  const ggembedi = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle(`Welcome to server <@${member.user.id}>`)
  .setColor('#11C3F7');

  channel.send(ggembedi); 

  let ggrolu = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Üye"); //give's auto role
  member.roles.add(ggrolu); //this to
});
```

i'm sorry about my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use any formatting or mention any `GuildMember` or `Role` in the `title` field of a `MessageEmbed`.

You are going to have to use the following instead:

```js
.setDescription(`Welcome to server ${member}`)
```

Not you can mention a user using their `User` or `GuildMember` object in a string so just use `member.user` or `member`.